# How to Make Border of 2D Game in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, collider

[image]

I have a border by default. But, I'm having trouble detecting if my object collides with the border. I am looking for efficient ways to do this, and I am not sure what should I use. I thought using a `Tilemap` might work. But, it was only giving me a grid, not a `Tilemap`. Even then, I was unable to figure out how to use the grid.
How should I go about creating this?

Comment: If you want "2D" objects to "Collide" then presumably you looked into the "Collider2D" components available in the engine? What have you tried based on your research so far?

Comment: @DMGregory I have added a Sprite Shape. I am able to detect collision. But, I have a question. When I increase/decrease resolution(screen size) those Sprite Shape goes away... Like I am unable to look at them...

Comment: There are like 10 different ways to move objects in Unity. And how to limit that movement would depend on which one you choose. Can you tell us more about how you are moving that square? By changing `transform.position`? Or by calling the method `rigidbody.AddForce`?

Comment: Regarding your question about your sprite disappearing when you change the screen resolution: That seems unrelated to the question you are asking here, so you should post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, you are trying to stop the player from moving out of the border. I would recommend doing this by using a Tilemap and adding a `Tilemap Collider` to the Grid inside the Tilemap GameObject. Then, simply just create a tile palette and add the chosen image for the border. Then, you can "draw" with the tile painter in the Palette Window. Also, by doing this, you can easily expand or shrink the border while developing, just by using the **Palette Tools**. You will also want to make sure you have the `IsTrigger` button unticked in the Grid Properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it such as suggested in the comment section (using tilemap collision) or you can do it programmatically:

```
if (playerX >= borderX && playerX <= borderX + borderWidth && 
    playerY >= borderY && playerY <= borderY + borderHeight)
   you touch a border
else
   player move
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `Sprite` and added `OnCollisionEnter2D`.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
    if(collision.collider.tag =="obstacle"){
       Debug.Log("Finish");
    }
}
```

This way I am able to detect collision.

Comment: In the question you stated that the tilemap didnt work out for you (at first?). Did you *just* add a tilemap and this function and that made it work? Or did you do anything else? (What is different here from what you did when you wrote the question?)